# Qt - How do I know which QTcpSocket emitted readyRead signal when there are several QTcpSocket in a class?

Tags: c++, qt

```
class SocketContainer {
private:
    QTcpSocket* m_sockets[10];
public:
    SocketContainer() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            connect(m_sockets[i], SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onNewData()));
    }
private slots:
    onNewData();
}
```

How can I know which socket emitted `readyRead` in `onNewData()` ?

Comment: I believe you can use QObject::sender function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *sender* as *Kourosh* suggested or maybe [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html#details) is better fitting your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's already answered, here is a snippet:

```
QObject *sigsender=sender();
if (sigsender) {
    DEBUG << " signal call objn: " << sigsender->objectName() << " clasn: " << sigsender->metaObject()->className();
} else {
    DEBUG << " direct call";
}
```